# how to minify js to one file using asset pipeline plugin in grails

Tags: grails, minify

Currently I am able to minify css/js using the asset-pipeline plugin. Each js/css files are minified separately.

Is there a way to minify the js all in one file and css in another file?

I have these currently setup in the config.groovy

```
grails.assets.minifyJs = true
grails.assets.minifyCss = true
grails.assets.bundle=true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely possible to combine all your CSS and JS into single files. This process is known as creating a `manifest`.

The first step is creating the manifest. Here is an example of one for a CSS files:

**assets/stylesheets/my-manifest.css**

```
/*
*= require file1.css
*= require file2.css
*/
```

And an example of one for JS files:

**assets/javascript/my-manifest.js**

```
//= require file1.js
//= require file2.js
```

Using these manifests within your GSP or Layout is quite simple:

```
<asset:stylesheet src="my-manifest.css" />
<asset:javascript src="my-manifest.js" />
```

In development mode the individual files will be included within the rendered source, but in production they will be single combined files based on your manifests.

Detailed information about the asset pipeline and manifests can be found in the documentation for [Manifests and Directives](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#directives).

Comment: How to we reference the js/css once they are in the manifest?

Comment: As shown in my answer you use the name of the manifest file as your asset. In my example I created two manifest files one called "my-manifest.css" and another called "my-manifest.js". In my example I used them in the following <asset:stylesheet> and <asset:javascript> tags within a GSP/Layout.